# NGINX different root for location

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to define a separate directory for each part of my website on my NGINX server.

```
domain.com/                     -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/website
domain.com/blog/                -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/blog
domain.com/checkout/            -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/checkout
domain.com/download/            -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/download
domain.com/forum/               -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/forum
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration solved my problem

```
server {
    location / { 
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    } 
    
    location /blog/  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/blog/;
    }
}
```

here is the complete version with correct PHP support

```
server {
    location / { 
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
            
            # do not remove
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }   
    } 

    location /blog/  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/blog/;
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 512k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 512k;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 512k;
            
            # do not remove
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html/domain.com/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }   
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

(debian 11 - nginx/1.18.0)